# Closest point to the origin from a Line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

1. Let the curve $C\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the image of the map $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$, given by $\gamma(t)=(t,t^2,t^3)$. Let $R$ be the tangent line to $C$ at $(1,1,1)$. Find the point of $R$ closest to the origin.

I have done this, is it right?

Because $\gamma(1)=(1,1,1)$, $R$ is the set
$$ (x,y,z)=(1,1,1)+t\gamma'(1),\quad t\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$ (x,y,z)=(1,1,1)+t(1,2,3),\quad t\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$ (x,y,z)=(1+t,1+2t,1+3t),\quad t\in\mathbb{R}$$

So I have to minimize the the function $f(t)=(1+t)^2+(1+2t)^2+(1+3t)^2=3+12t+14t^2$. I see that
$$f'(t)=12+28t=0\iff t=-3/7.$$

So, $(x,y,z)=(1-3/7,1-2(3/7),1-3(3/7))=(4/7,1/7,-2/7)$ is the point in $R$ closest to the origin.

Thanks

Comment: That all seems correct, except that $12+28t=0 \implies t=-12/28 = -3/7$.

Comment: You're right, thank you!!

Comment: You can also use the fact that the point on a line closest to the origin is the point $p$ where the vector from the origin to $p$ is orthogonal to the direction of the line. In this case, this means that you need to solve $(1+t,1+2t,1+3t)\cdot(1,2,3)=0$, which quickly leads to the same solution.